# codeigniter create ci_session table crashes mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, create-table, sequelpro

crashes after running Codeigniter create table my sql query to create session table :

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ci_sessions (
id varchar(128) NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
timestamp int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
data blob NOT NULL,
KEY ci_sessions_timestamp (timestamp)
);`

i tried to create this table from command line but it is the same issue when i open sequel pro

Comment: what do you mean crash? stops responding?

Comment: Yes and I can't connect again . I can only after initialize mysql and strart mysql but it will delete all databases and start fresh . When I run again the SQL command I have the same issues.

Comment: can you create other tables?

Comment: Yes . But this SQL was provided by codeigniter docs to create session table. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

Comment: i only ask because plenty of people, including myself, have used that same sql query to make the sessions table thus it only makes sense that it would fail if other queries failed (issue with your server). i cannot explain why this is happening and a lack of error doesn't help.

Comment: It could be but I could not figure it out .